# Unpivoting data and filling null values to get current state from state changes in R

Tags: sql, r, tableau-api, unpivot

I have scoured the web for a solution on this, however, been unable to find an answer to this specific topic.

I have a dataframe showing data of 19 different units, that each have 2 departments. These departments can be in different states (state 1-5), and must be in a state at all times.

The data itself looks like this:

```
Time        department      fromState   toState Date
46051.41923 unit36:depr2    4           5       2017-05-22 10:47
46077.33833 unit37:depr1    3           4       2017-05-22 10:47
47057.31889 unit31:depr2    2           3       2017-05-22 11:04
47062.31889 unit31:depr1    3           6       2017-05-22 11:04
```

The data shows what state each department was before the state change (fromState) and will be after state change (toState).

What I would rather have is this:

```
Date               unit36:depr2   unit37:depr1   unit31:depr2   unit31:depr1
2017-05-22 10:47    5              4              2              3
2017-05-22 11:04    5              4              3              6
```

This is so I can see what state all units are in at all times. As you can probably see I have merged the fromState and toState manually into columns with the unit&depr name. I have also removed duplicate Date values. The time column was used to make the Date column and has also been deleted.

Is there any way I can do this in a non-manual way?

Comment: It isn't clear to me *which* of `fromState` and `toState` are being used *where* in your desired output. I would probably use `tidyr::spread` for this, but I can't see through the data yet.

Comment: Or perhaps a different question: from your sample data, how did you derive data for `unit31:depr2` at time `2017-05-22 10:47`?

Comment: Is there a typo in the desired output? There is only one 5 in the input, but 2 in the output. And there are three 3s in the input but only 2 in the output.

Comment: @r2evans I used the toState values on the time the change happend and after. I used the fromState values before that state happens.

So in my output table, [1,2] I used the toState, as at this time unit36:depr2 changes to state 5. in [1,3] I use fromState, as this unit ( unit31:depr2) has not changed at this point and is still in state 2.

Does this clarify?

Comment: @MrFlick no typo, as the unitdepr remains in this state at that datetime.

Comment: This can be done in tableau but for time 10:47 there is no data for unit 31 but required out put table is showing data... is the sample data you provided is correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @Siva All my data is correct. The reason we know the data for 10:47 for unit 31 is that in 11:04 it changes to 3 from state 2. That way we know that it has previously been state 2.

Comment: Ok fine, it should be presumed that if there is no data available then we need to presume the value one state less than the current state, Is that correct? If it is correct then we are trying to get a value to display in report that doesn't exist in database, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct. With that logic my output table would be wrong. Departments can change freely between states and are not bound by any sequence. I'm very interested in a Tableau solution, but in regards of R, both MrFlick and r2evans got a correct solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another strategy using tidyverse functions. First, your data

```
library(tidyverse)
dd <- read_csv("Time,department,fromState,toState,Date
46051.41923,unit36:depr2,4,5,2017-05-22 10:47
46077.33833,unit37:depr1,3,4,2017-05-22 10:47
47057.31889,unit31:depr2,2,3,2017-05-22 11:04
47062.31889,unit31:depr1,3,6,2017-05-22 11:04")
```

Now I get the first date for each department

```
start <- dd %>% 
  group_by(department) %>% 
  summarize(state=first(fromState)) %>% 
  spread(department, state)
```

Now for each date, I get all the current states

```
changes <- dd %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  select(Date, department, toState) %>% 
  split(.$Date)  %>% 
  map(spread, department, toState)
```

Then I use `accumulate` to "replay" the changes for each date.

```
alt_list_modify <- function(x, y) list_modify(x, !!!y)
final <- accumulate(changes, alt_list_modify, .init = start) %>% 
  tail(-1) %>% bind_rows()
```

This returns the desired result

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  `unit31:depr1` `unit31:depr2` `unit36:depr2` `unit37:depr1`                Date
           <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>              <dttm>
1              3              2              5              4 2017-05-22 10:47:00
2              6              3              5              4 2017-05-22 11:04:00
```

Comment: I suggest against using `library(tidyverse)`, especially in answers, since it is not immediately obvious which packages you strictly need, and there can be a lot of unnecessary cruft in there.

Comment: The simplicity of just including everything someone needs is why I recommend to new users to just use `library(tidyverse)`. Why bother loading a bunch of different packages when you can just load them all at once. I don't see any harmful sides effects of "cruft". I prefer simple. it's rare in my experience to every just use one tidyverse package on it's own in the wild.

Comment: Have they finally fixed `purrr` functions masking `dplyr` functions? (Right, I see [the issue is closed](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/343).) That was one of my bigger rationale. I still think answers can be "teaching moments", and while I understand sometimes you need an "easy" button, I also feel that explicit clarity is often just as useful. Regardless, it's just preference.

Comment: Unfortunately, in corporate (esp. banking) environments you often have to seek formal approval to use specific packages. It may be the case that e.g. `dplyr` has been approved but other `tidyverse` packages have not. But, I can understand why you might want to ignore that use-case given how ridiculous that situation is.

Comment: @Renu then you might as well get all the useful ones out of the way by just installing "tidyverse".

Comment: My point was that doing so is not an option in that case, because corporate firewalls have blocked all but specific packages.

Comment: @r2evans agreed. it's just preference. but thanks for making me spend some time thinking about it.

Comment: @Renu what? a firewall will either block CRAN or not. Are you saying it blocks individual URLs from all the CRAN mirrors? that doesn't make sense. if you can convince someone to allow ggplot2, then the same argument would work for convincing them to use tidyverse.

Comment: Blocking packages at the firewall? That's some stateful inspection! Dang ... understood, but getting `tidyverse` approved as a package and choosing to use `library(tidyverse)` versus `library(dplyr)` are two different things. Are you saying that the approval of individual functions is based on the libraries they explicitly import? That's rather draconian. Would you care to highlight (shame) a company that actually goes to that detail/effort? Mostly just curious.

Comment: @MrFlick, just curious, if you use python do you use `import packagename` or `from packagename import *`? Namespace collisions (by masking) is a slight weakness of R (and py's `from ... import *`), and though I'm used to it, that does not mean there aren't better ways (on a language level) of handling it. I'm not suggesting python is the only or best, but "collide by scope" can be problematic if not explicitly chosen.

Comment: @r2evans good point. since python has proper name spacing I tend to use it. but i guess in my mind the tidyverse package have all become one thing. I rarely ever use one on it's own in the wild. Just like i don't think about if `hist()` comes from "base" or "graphics" or "stats" or "utils", I use them all together as one. And I often encourage new users to R to do the same just to simplify the mental model of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at your data a little differently. Instead of "from" and "to", I think you should consider an "initial state" and then invoke a change whenever it happens. Using your data (adding "x" here to easily deal with `read.table(text=...)`, please use your own data):

```
x <- read.table(text='Time        department      fromState   toState Date x
46051.41923 unit36:depr2    4           5       2017-05-22 10:47
46077.33833 unit37:depr1    3           4       2017-05-22 10:47
47057.31889 unit31:depr2    2           3       2017-05-22 11:04
47062.31889 unit31:depr1    3           6       2017-05-22 11:04', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x$Date <- as.POSIXct(paste(x$Date, x$x))
x$x <- NULL
```

I'm going to use two libraries for this, because I think they are appropriate here and easy to read. I'm confident somebody can suggest `data.table` (likely faster) and base-R (not package-dependent) solutions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

The first thing is to determine the starting state for all departments. (The `0` date is just "before anything else happened".)

```
initial_state <- x %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(department) %>%
  summarize(
    date = as.POSIXct(0, origin='1970-01-01'),
    state = fromState[1]
  )
initial_state
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#     department       date state
#          <chr>     <dttm> <int>
# 1 unit31:depr1 1970-01-01     3
# 2 unit31:depr2 1970-01-01     2
# 3 unit36:depr2 1970-01-01     4
# 4 unit37:depr1 1970-01-01     3
```

Now record when things change:

```
transitions <- select(x, department, date = Date, state = toState)
transitions
#     department                date state
# 1 unit36:depr2 2017-05-22 10:47:00     5
# 2 unit37:depr1 2017-05-22 10:47:00     4
# 3 unit31:depr2 2017-05-22 11:04:00     3
# 4 unit31:depr1 2017-05-22 11:04:00     6
```

The next step is to do the unpivoting:

```
bind_rows(initial_state, transitions) %>%
  spread(department, state)
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#                  date `unit31:depr1` `unit31:depr2` `unit36:depr2` `unit37:depr1`
# *              <dttm>          <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
# 1 1970-01-01 00:00:00              3              2              4              3
# 2 2017-05-22 10:47:00             NA             NA              5              4
# 3 2017-05-22 11:04:00              6              3             NA             NA
```

... realizing that an `NA` means *"nothing happened this day for this department, so carry-forward from the previous non-`NA` row"*. Fortunately, there's a function in the [`zoo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package that does just this:

> na.locf                  package:zoo                   R Documentation
>
> Last Observation Carried Forward
>
> Description:
>
> Generic function for replacing each 'NA' with the most recent
>        non-'NA' prior to it.

```
library(zoo) # for clarity, not strictly requires since I use '::' here
bind_rows(initial_state, transitions) %>%
  spread(department, state) %>%
  mutate_all(zoo::na.locf) %>%
  filter(date > 0) # since I no longer need the "0" date
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
#                  date `unit31:depr1` `unit31:depr2` `unit36:depr2` `unit37:depr1`
#                <dttm>          <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
# 1 2017-05-22 10:47:00              3              2              5              4
# 2 2017-05-22 11:04:00              6              3              5              4
```